# C# unable to establish SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a basic form with an 'Add Recipe' button which is meant to write the following to me SQL Server Express database:

1. Recipe Name
2. Recipe Ingredients
3. Recipe Instructions
4. Recipe Image

The form is located at the bottom of the question and when I click the 'Add Recipe' button it makes a call to the `updatedate()` method, this method looks like so:

```
private void updatedata()
{ 
        // filestream object to read the image
        // full length of image to a byte array
        try
        {
                // try to see if the image has a valid path
                if (imagename != "")
                {
                    FileStream fs;
                    fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    // a byte array to read the image
                    byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();

                    //open the database using odp.net and insert the lines
                    string connstr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RecipeOrganiser;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";

                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
                    conn.Open();
                    string query;
                    query = "insert into Recipes(RecipeName,RecipeImage,RecipeIngredients,RecipeInstructions) values (" + textBox1.Text + "," + " @pic" + "," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + ")";

                    SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
                    picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
                    picparameter.ParameterName = "pic";
                    picparameter.Value = picbyte;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved");
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    Connection();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

My problem is when ever I click the 'Add recipe' button with the information populated, it freezes for around 30 seconds and then displays the following error, I have checked that the SQL Server services are running which thy are. Can anyone offer ay advice what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

**Image of Form**

[image]

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You dont specify the server address and password. Also you should probably use prepared statements and a "using" around your sql connection.

Comment: For SQL Server **Express**, by default, your server instance is called `SQLEXPRESS`. So try this in your connection string: `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;....`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned SQL injection is not an issue, this is a test project on my home PC

Comment: SQL injection is **ALWAYS** an issue, and you should not be writing shoddy code just because it's a "pet project" on your home PC .....

Comment: I changed the datasource to .\SQLEXPRESS and I got the following "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Comment: Sorry marc_s I am just following the following exercise as a learning process:http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/

Comment: Sounds like the SQL Server service process isn't running ....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39597/discussion-between-selectdistinct-and-marc-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string connstr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RecipeOrganiser;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";
```

needs to be

```
 string connstr = @"Server=localhost\{SERVER_NAME};Database=RecipeOrganiser;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

you can get the SERVER_NAME from the property value "Name" user the SQL server properties

Comment: I login using windows authentication, I have not set an sa password how do I find out what this is by default?

Comment: so it needs to be "Server=localhost;Database=RecipeOrganiser;Trusted_Connection=True;"

Comment: Still does not connect

Comment: right click on the server (the little icon with greed arrow on it) go to properties ,use the property value under "Name" to replace the localhost in your connection string

Comment: This seems to work, I'm no longer getting connection based errors, please update your answer and I will flag it as accepted, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=sa;Password=yoursqlserverpassword");
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

your connection string doesn't look good to me ... try using .Net SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to create a valid connection string ... set DataSource, InitialCatalog and IntegratedSecurity or UserId and Password properties